# How to link two objects in a jsp result?

Tags: spring, jsp

I have a controller that gets all the news from a database and at the same time, it counts the number of comments on each of the news, but I have a problem because even when the data is correctly pulled out of the database, the jsp does not mix each news object with its corresponding comment count...

Here is my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewstatus", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView viewStatus(ModelAndView modelAndView, @RequestParam(name = "p", defaultValue = "1") int pageNumber) {

    Page<StatusUpdate> page = statusUpdateService.getPage(pageNumber);

    for(StatusUpdate statusUpdate: page){

        SiteUser siteUser= statusUpdate.getSiteUser();

        modelAndView.getModel().put("siteuser", siteUser);

        int countComments = commentService.countStatusComments(statusUpdate);

        modelAndView.getModel().put("commentscounter", countComments);
    }

    modelAndView.getModel().put("page", page);

    modelAndView.setViewName("app.viewStatus");

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Here is the console result:

> !!!!!! STATUSUPDATECONTROLLER: viewOneStatus : Count del comment: 2
>   !!!!! VIEWSTATUS statusUpdate: StatusUpdate [id=98, title=Title97, text=Status update 97, added=2017-06-28 12:52:04.0, siteUser=SiteUser [id=1, email=test@caveofprogramming.com, plainPassword=null, password=$2a$10$TlfLjCcq8vPZHYkWcZ4rwurnqx5/g5C.5nk3hGTdiG6/cxlx1COPq, enabled=true, firstname=Mike, surname=River, repeatPassword=null, role=ROLE_ADMIN]]
>   2017-03-24 21:00:23.278 DEBUG 1080 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select count(comment0_.id) as col_0_0_ from comments comment0_ left outer join status_update statusupda1_ on comment0_.statusupdateid=statusupda1_.id where statusupda1_.id=?
>   Hibernate: select count(comment0_.id) as col_0_0_ from comments comment0_ left outer join status_update statusupda1_ on comment0_.statusupdateid=statusupda1_.id where statusupda1_.id=?
>   !!!!!! STATUSUPDATECONTROLLER: viewOneStatus : Count del comment: 1
>   !!!!! VIEWSTATUS statusUpdate: StatusUpdate [id=97, title=Title96, text=Status update 96, added=2017-06-27 12:52:04.0, siteUser=SiteUser [id=1, email=test@caveofprogramming.com, plainPassword=null, password=$2a$10$TlfLjCcq8vPZHYkWcZ4rwurnqx5/g5C.5nk3hGTdiG6/cxlx1COPq, enabled=true, firstname=Mike, surname=River, repeatPassword=null, role=ROLE_ADMIN]]
>   2017-03-24 21:00:23.280 DEBUG 1080 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select count(comment0_.id) as col_0_0_ from comments comment0_ left outer join status_update statusupda1_ on comment0_.statusupdateid=statusupda1_.id where statusupda1_.id=?
>   Hibernate: select count(comment0_.id) as col_0_0_ from comments comment0_ left outer join status_update statusupda1_ on comment0_.statusupdateid=statusupda1_.id where statusupda1_.id=?
>   !!!!!! STATUSUPDATECONTROLLER: viewOneStatus : Count del comment: 0
>   !!!!! VIEWSTATUS statusUpdate: StatusUpdate [id=96, title=Title95, text=Status update 95, added=2017-06-26 12:52:04.0, siteUser=SiteUser [id=1, email=test@caveofprogramming.com, plainPassword=null, password=$2a$10$TlfLjCcq8vPZHYkWcZ4rwurnqx5/g5C.5nk3hGTdiG6/cxlx1COPq, enabled=true, firstname=Mike, surname=River, repeatPassword=null, role=ROLE_ADMIN]]
>   2017-03-24 21:00:23.282 DEBUG 1080 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select count(comment0_.id) as col_0_0_ from comments comment0_ left outer join status_update statusupda1_ on comment0_.statusupdateid=statusupda1_.id where statusupda1_.id=?
>   Hibernate: select count(comment0_.id) as col_0_0_ from comments comment0_ left outer join status_update statusupda1_ on comment0_.statusupdateid=statusupda1_.id where statusupda1_.id=?
>   !!!!!! STATUSUPDATECONTROLLER: viewOneStatus : Count del comment: 0
>   !!!!! VIEWSTATUS statusUpdate: StatusUpdate [id=95, title=Title94, text=Status update 94, added=2017-06-25 12:52:04.0, siteUser=SiteUser [id=1, email=test@caveofprogramming.com, plainPassword=null, password=$2a$10$TlfLjCcq8vPZHYkWcZ4rwurnqx5/g5C.5nk3hGTdiG6/cxlx1COPq, enabled=true, firstname=Mike, surname=River, repeatPassword=null, role=ROLE_ADMIN]]
>   2017-03-24 21:00:23.284 DEBUG 1080 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select count(comment0_.id) as col_0_0_ from comments comment0_ left outer join status_update statusupda1_ on comment0_.statusupdateid=statusupda1_.id where statusupda1_.id=?
>   Hibernate: select count(comment0_.id) as col_0_0_ from comments comment0_ left outer join status_update statusupda1_ on comment0_.statusupdateid=statusupda1_.id where statusupda1_.id=?
>   !!!!!! STATUSUPDATECONTROLLER: viewOneStatus : Count del comment: 0

Here is the JSP:

```
<table class="table table-hover">                               
    <c:forEach var="statusUpdate" items="${page.content}">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul class="list-inline posted-info">
                    <li>By
                        <a href="${contextRoot}/profile/${statusUpdate.siteUser.id}">
                            ${statusUpdate.siteUser.firstname}
                            ${statusUpdate.siteUser.surname}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>Posted</li>
                    <li>
                        <fmt:formatDate pattern="EEEE d MMMM y 'at' H:mm:ss" value="${statusUpdate.added}" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h2>
                    <a href="${contextRoot}/viewonestatus/${statusUpdate.id}">${statusUpdate.title}></a>
                </h2>
                 <p>${statusUpdate.text}</p> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul class="post-shares">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"> <i class="rounded-x icon-speech"></i>
                            <span>${commentscounter}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="rounded-x icon-share"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="rounded-x icon-heart"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>                   
    </c:forEach>                                
</table>
```

And here comes the result (0 for all the comments when it is not true):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how do you add `commentscouner` into the model.

```
for(StatusUpdate statusUpdate: page){
    SiteUser siteUser= statusUpdate.getSiteUser();
    modelAndView.getModel().put("siteuser", siteUser);
    int countComments = commentService.countStatusComments(statusUpdate);

    // next line is a cause of problem
    modelAndView.getModel().put("commentscounter", countComments);
}
```

Every time you set new value with the same name: `commentscouner`. Therefore every time you override the value added on previous iteration of the loop. That means when the loop will be finished the model will contain just last value of `countComments`. And if last value is `0`, the JSP will output `0` for all records.

So you have to store comment count for every `StatusUpdate` separately. For example in the map:

```
HashMap<StatusUpdate, Integer> counterMap = new HashMap<StatusUpdate, Integer>();

for(StatusUpdate statusUpdate: page){
    ...
    int countComments = commentService.countStatusComments(statusUpdate);       
    counterMap.put(statusUpdate, countComments);
}
modelAndView.put("counterMap", counterMap);
```

Now, in JSP you can output values of the map:

```
<table class="table table-hover">                               
    <c:forEach var="statusUpdate" items="${page.content}">
        ...
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul class="post-shares">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"> 
                            <i class="rounded-x icon-speech"></i>
                            <span>${counterMap[statusUpdate]}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="rounded-x icon-share"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="rounded-x icon-heart"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>                   
    </c:forEach>                                
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect fix. Thanks a lot.